# Java import sub-sub directory

Tags: java

My directory structure looks like this:

```
folder
└───subfolder
    └───subsubfolder
```

I hava a Main.java in `folder` and `Main.java` uses class inside `subsubfolder`.
Here is how I did:

```
import subfolder.*;
import subfolder.subsubfolder.*;
```

However, I got the message following when I execute `javac Main.java`

```
$ javac -g Main.java
Main.java:23: error: cannot access Node
      Node root = new Node();
      ^
  bad class file: ./subfolder/subsubfolder/Node.class
    class file contains wrong class: subsubfolder.Node
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
1 error
```

Is my way of importing class file wrong?

Comment: import subfolder.subsubfolder.*; <= replace directory separator with .

Comment: Oops, it's typo. Actually I did it in your way. I still have an issue above.

Comment: What is the `package` declaration in `Node`?

Comment: Can you share the source for your `Node` class - at least the package and class definitions?

Comment: It says package `subfolder`.

Comment: @PeterHwang the rule is quite simple: the package hierarchy must match the folder hierarchy. Decide of a root folder for your sources. All the classes in this root folderare in the default package. All the classes in a subdirectory must be in a package which matches the directory path from the root folder.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ***It says `package subfolder`***

The package declaration of `Node` should say

```
package subfolder.subsubfolder;
```

Providing an example for clarity:

```
folder/
        Your source root (typically called 'src')

folder/Main.java
        class Main { ... }  (no package declaration)

folder/subfolder

folder/subfolder/subsubfolder/Node.java
        package subfolder.subsubfolder;
        public class Node { ... }
```

If your `Main` indeed lives in a package (i.e. if your situation is something like `src/folder/Main.java`) then you should **not** do

```
cd src/folder
javac Main.java
```

you should do

```
cd src
javac folder/Main.java
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Node class declares that it belongs to package `subsubfolder`, but it *should* belong to package `subfolder.subsubfolder`.  Alternatively, you could move directory `subfolder/subsubfolder` to be a sibling of directory `subfolder`.